# Content filtering with AWS Event Patterns | How to combine 'anything-but' & 'prefix' events

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-cloudwatch

Question Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html

***I am trying to make use of CloudWatch events to trigger events when a file is dropped into an S3 bucket.
I am using the below to trigger if any file is dropped into test-buckt1/in whose file name doesnt start wih BP.***

```
{
"detail": {
"eventName": ["PutObject"],
"eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
"requestParameters": {
"bucketName": ["test-buckt1"],
"key": [
   {
     "anything-but": {
         "prefix": "in/BP"
      }
    }
   ]
}
},
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"]
}
```

**PROBLEM: This gets triggered even if a file is dropped to some other object say test-buckt1/out folder.
I could use this the below but I will have to add the logic to filter file names starting with BP in my lamdba code -**

```
{
"detail": {
"eventName": ["PutObject"],
"eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
"requestParameters": {
"bucketName": ["test-buckt1"],
"key": [
   { "prefix": "in/"
   }]
}
},
"detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
"source": ["aws.s3"]
}
```

**Any way where we can combine the above. So A rule which should only trigger when a file is dropped to test-buckt1/in folder AND it should not trigger when the file name dropped in test/buckt1/in starts with BP**